# How to iterate effectively in Linux kernel development

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm fairly new to Linux kernel development. It is certainly quite a bit different than the Windows kernel (I am a recovering Microsoft engineer). Can you provide advice on how to iterate effectively on updating modules that come with the Linux kernel?

Specifically, I am updating hid and bcm5974 to support the latest Macbook Pro (early 2015), and am using Ubuntu 15.04 (kernel 3.19). Would you recommend I test it out in a Virtual Machine? Are there ways to incrementally build instead of clean + build the whole tree? I'd love to be able to build just the affected modules but I can't find a good way to do that. The Makefiles are rather complicated.

Comment: a vm would certainly save you from having to constantly reboot your dev machine... especially if you don't have another box to test the code on.

Comment: Couple of links. [**KernelBuild**](http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelBuild)  and [**How to Compile Linux Kernel**](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/06/compile-linux-kernel/)  and [**How to Compile the Linux Kernel**](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/362602-how-to-compile-the-linux-kernel)

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin. I've read articles such as those but I haven't found one that calls out incremental builds (ie, I changed one c or header and don't want a full rebuild) or building just a single module

Answer (score 1):

Time to answer my own question. After doing a full build, incrementals are pretty straightforward given you're not editing headers that are consumed by other modules.

make modules SUBDIRS=drivers/input/mouse

Once I've installed the kernel from the full build, iterating on new module compilations is a breeze. sudo rmmod bcm5974. scp file from build desktop to Macbook Pro. sudo insmod bcm5974.